# Error generating .pdf using knitr to PDF in RStudio

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, pdflatex

From RStudio I have created a new file, File / New File / R Markdown, I have tried to generate the .pdf file from knitr / knitr to PDF, and the error that I reproduce below occurs, I am starting with LaTeX and I do not know very well what make. I appreciate your help.

Console RStudio:

```
! Sorry, but C:\Users\JOSCAR~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.

! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

!   C:\Users\JoséCarlos\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.
```

pdflatex.log

```
2021-05-25 23:58:56,093+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (4356) started by 'Rterm' with command line: C:\Users\JOSCAR~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode test.tex
2021-05-25 23:58:56,384+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2021-05-25 23:58:57,143+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2021-05-25 23:58:57,196+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2021-05-25 23:59:42,047+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2021-05-25 23:59:42,047+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Data: 
2021-05-25 23:59:42,047+0200 FATAL pdflatex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp:126
2021-05-25 23:59:42,265+0200 FATAL pdflatex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2021-05-25 23:59:42,291+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: 
2021-05-25 23:59:42,291+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2021-05-25 23:59:42,291+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 126
2021-05-25 23:59:42,316+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (4356) finishes with exit code 1
```

Comment: Are you able to create a very basic latex document and compile it to PDF without using R, Rstudio, or knitr?  i.e., grab a [latex editor](https://guides.nyu.edu/LaTeX/sample-document) and compile just: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} hello world \end{document}`

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27141): `Remedy: start MiKTeX Options and choose either Yes or No (but not "Ask me first") for the option "Install missing packages on-the-fly"`

Comment: @Dany, I can compile it and see it, also in adobe acrobat reader

Comment: @jared_mamrot, ok, It has been the solution for me in this case

Comment: I have installed proTeXt, I see that I have two applications, MikTeX 2.9 version 2.9 and I also see MikTeX version 21.2 installed, is this normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments, the answer posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27141 solved the issue.

The relevant part:

> Remedy: start MiKTeX Options and choose either Yes or No (but not "Ask
> me first") for the option "Install missing packages on-the-fly"

Comment: In my case, from the MikTeX console, with the LaTeX proTeXt distribution installation, in Settings, You can choose whether missing packages are to be installed automatically (on-the-fly): "Always" option